# Call GIF image source from the code behind in WPF c# for the tabcontrol's setter

Tags: c#, wpf

i am using wpf tab control and setting the Icon and text in the tab header through style, i am able to set the text dynamically through getter and setter but can not able to set the image source. I tried to bind the image source through getter and setter but failed. Following is the style code in which i want to set the image source dynamically from the code behind.
  
            -->

```
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" >

            <Setter.Value>

                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!--<Image   gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{DynamicResource MyFillBrush}"  Width="20" />-->

                        <Image   gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="25.gif"  Width="20" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding }"/>

                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old thread, but this is how you update the AnimatedSource from code:

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri(value);
image.EndInit();
ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(Imagereference, image);
```

The 'value' is the location of your gif file such as "25.gif".
The Imagereference is the Image control you want to update.  Also ensure you have the namespace referenced: using WpfAnimatedGif;

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use Binding, something like

```
private string _dynamicGif = "test.gif";
public string DynamicGif
{
    get { return _dynamicGif; }
    private set
    {
        _dynamicGif = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DynamicGif");
    }
}
```

and

```
<Image   gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding DynamicGif, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Width="20" />
```

Or, if it doesn't work, you can use `MediaElement` instead of `Image`, it won't require WPF Animated GIF. It's also pretty simple to use:

```
private Uri _imgSource = new Uri("test.gif");
public Uri ImgSource
{
    get { return _imgSource; }
    private set
    {
        _imgSource = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ImgSource");
    }
}
```

and

```
<MediaElement x:Name="gifImg" LoadedBehavior="Play" Width="20" Source="{Binding ImgSource}"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I won't able to call RaisePropertyChanged, How can i call it?

Comment: @Ebaad, not sure if I understood your question. Do you mean you're not able to set those properties in the view model or code-behind? How do you change Label's text, is it bound to some property?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly i mean, i am not able to call that image tag in the code behind so that i can change the images run time or disable the visibility when needed.

Comment: @Ebaad, sorry for this misunderstanding, but can you elaborate on why you cannot set properties from code behind? How is the Label's text updated?

Comment: Label text updated by using the following line
<Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=LabelText}"/>

Comment: @Ebaad, so you have a property called `LabelText` in either your view model or codebehind. Just add the same property (copy-paste that `DynamicGif` part) to your codebehind and set it in the same manner you set `LabelText`.

Comment: the LabelText is binding on the header but the Image is binding inside the setter-> DataTemplate->StackPanel

Comment: @Ebaad, maybe if you could post your project/solution somewhere, I would be able to help.

Comment: Its just a tabcontrol style and im setting the HeaderTemplate not sure why u want the whole project, i just shared the problem relevant code in my question above. i just only want to call the image in the code behind..

Comment: @Ebaad, sorry, but I really don't understand the problem. There are two working solutions (I'm not saying they're the most elegant or anything, but they are working) where you can set GIF images from codebehind/view model. And you don't want to explain what the issue with using them is.

Comment: Issue in your solution is that i can't able to call RaisePropertyChanged, it says it does not exist in the current context, i can't able to understand how can i able to call this..

Comment: @Ebaad, now that's a different story :) Do you have `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented for your codebehind class? If not, you can add its implementation: `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) { if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }`. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface)